# React Redux, how to think about structuring one model with multiple data types?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm creating a react redux app that allows users to rate and view their ratings... I will have the following API methods:

- Rating#Create (Where you post a rating on a user)
- Rating#Index (Where you get a JSON object of the ratings about the current user)

I'm confused on how to create my reducer. Given the data-models between the two methods above are different

My `ratingReducer.js` looks like the following:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = []

export default function ratingReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  //console.log('ratingReducer');
  //console.log(action)
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.CREATE_RATING_SUCCESS:
      return action.rating
    case types.LOAD_YOURRATINGS_SUCCESS:
      return action.your_ratings
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Am I doing this right? Or should I be having two separate reducers?

```
store.rating (current_user posts a rating on another user)
store.your_ratings (ratings about the current user)
```

One or two reducers and why? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it right.  There would be no compelling reason to put rating in different reducers.  I tend to think of the major sections of my app, and the state those sections will need, and factor my reducers accordingly.  If you wanted, you could have one giant reducer for you entire app.  Or, you could break it up in a bunch of tiny reducers.  It's up to you.